# How to remove a specified word from a string the first time it appears

Tags: java, string

i'm having trouble with my code. 
It works in most cases for example taking 'cool' out of the following: Nagash is cool really cool, turns into Nagash is really cool.
But something like taking 'ish' out of the following: Nagash is coolish, turns into Nagash is cooh.

I am very new to java and my code has to be written in loops and such with NO shortcut methods. If you reply could you please write you answer how it would be written in java like my code.

```
String deleteFromString(String word, String remove) {       
    String updated = "";    

    int count = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;

    if (stringEquals(remove, "")) {
        updated = word;
        return updated;
    }

    while (count < length(word)) {
        if (getChar(word, count) == getChar(remove, start)) {
            if (getChar(word, count + length(remove) - 1) == getChar(remove, length(remove) - 1)) {
                start = count;
                end = count + length(remove) - 1; 


                println(count);
                println(count + length(remove) - 1);
                count = length(word);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    count = 0;
    while (count < start - 1) {
        updated += getChar(word, count);
        count++;

    }

    while (end < length(word)) {
        updated += getChar(word, end);
        end++;

    }
    println(updated);   


    return updated;        
}
```

Comment: Fire up you debugger and step through your code using input data that produces a wrong result.

Comment: This code has multiple tests that has to pass. Each time it recieves a string and another string that has to be omitted from the original.

Comment: You syntax is not java, wrong tag?

Comment: @user1933888 What's wrong with it?

Comment: @user1933888 I think you should post this comment some where else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in your final two while loops. In the first of the two, the loop will terminate two characters before the start of your 'remove' substring instead of at the character before. In the second, the loop begins at the position of the 'end' character and therefore includes it. In your example case the final character is included because the index of the final character will always be one less than the length of the string. This gives the effect of shifting the deleted substring one character to the left in the parent string. Try instead:

```
while (count < start) {
    updated += getChar(word, count);
    count++;

}

while (end + 1 < length(word)) {
    updated += getChar(word, end + 1);
    end++;

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply :) I will test this in the morning. May I ask how come my code works in some cases but not others? Cheers

Comment: That works! Thankyou. The only test that wouldn't work with your answer was when a word to be removed didn't appear in the String. This made the first letter get missed out when outputting to the String since the count is 0 and start is 0. I fixed this by putting an IF after the main loop to check whether both start and end = 0, if they didi I just returned 'word'.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the source code of [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) replace method.

```
public static String replace(final String text, final String searchString, final String replacement, int max) {
    if (isEmpty(text) || isEmpty(searchString) || replacement == null || max == 0) {
        return text;
    }
    int start = 0;
    int end = text.indexOf(searchString, start);
    if (end == INDEX_NOT_FOUND) {
        return text;
    }
    final int replLength = searchString.length();
    int increase = replacement.length() - replLength;
    increase = increase < 0 ? 0 : increase;
    increase *= max < 0 ? 16 : max > 64 ? 64 : max;
    final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(text.length() + increase);
    while (end != INDEX_NOT_FOUND) {
        buf.append(text.substring(start, end)).append(replacement);
        start = end + replLength;
       if (--max == 0) {
            break;
        }
        end = text.indexOf(searchString, start);
   }
    buf.append(text.substring(start));
    return buf.toString();
}


public static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence cs) {
    return cs == null || cs.length() == 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To keep it simple do it this way:

```
 String test="Nagash is coolish";
 test=test.replaceFirst("ish", "");
 System.out.println(test);
```

**Output :**

```
Nagash is cool
```

**EDIT :**
Here is complete code to handle number of `strings` with replaces.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      Test test=new Test();
      String result=test.computeRemove("this is demo and demo", "demo", "one");
      // you can pass different parameters for desired result.
      System.out.println(result);
  }
  public String computeRemove(String main,String remove, String replace) {
      main=main.replaceFirst(remove,replace);
      return main;
  }
}
```

For more on such `String` operations visit [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm) link.

Comment: As per OP `my code has to be written in loops and such with NO shortcut methods`

Comment: @downvoters - Showing another way isn't exactly wrong. I agree if you don't up-vote the answer. But down-voting (I think) is wrong in this case.

Comment: I need one bit of code that can handle a variety of input strings and strings to be removed :)